# cmake won't build a Linux c++11 cross-compiled program with pthreads

Tags: linux, c++11, cmake, pthreads, cross-compiling

In a nutshell, I can build the program with a direct g++ command line.  It builds then executes successfully on the target.

If, however, I use the simplest cmake script I can think of, the build succeeds, but the program fails to execute on the target.  The failed output of the executable is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted
```

The g++ command line I use for a successful build and execution is:

```
/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o ThreadTest -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp ThreadTest.cpp
```

When I run the straight g++ program on the target, I get:

```
Atomic Success Count: 1000 of 1000.

Mutex Success Count: 1000 of 1000.

Unclean Success Count: 922 of 1000.
Unclean Failure Count: 78 of 1000.
```

The CMakeLists.txt file I use is:

```
# cmake file for building the ThreadTest executable.  This requires c++11.
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.12)

# !!! Set up the compiler to use, first (i.e. before the PROJECT() call.)
# gcc location.
SET(CROSS_COMPILE_FULL
   "/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-")
# sysroot location
SET(CROSS_COMPILE_FULL_HOST
   "/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/arm926ejste-criticallink-linux-gnueabi")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CROSS_COMPILE_FULL}gcc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CROSS_COMPILE_FULL}g++")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${CROSS_COMPILE_FULL_HOST}")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# The project will use the compiler specified above (or the default compiler for Windows.)
PROJECT(CommonSDK)

SET(MY_TEST_HOME "$ENV{TEST_HOME}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")

SET(CUR_PROJECT_NAME ThreadTest)
SET(PROJECT_HOME_DIR "${MY_TEST_HOME}/${CUR_PROJECT_NAME}")
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "$ENV{TEST_EXEC_HOME}")

FILE(GLOB CUR_PROJECT_FILES "${PROJECT_HOME_DIR}/*.cpp" "${PROJECT_HOME_DIR}/*.h")

FIND_PACKAGE(Threads REQUIRED)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${CUR_PROJECT_NAME} ${CUR_PROJECT_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CUR_PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

I invoke cmake with:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

And the cmake output is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build
```

Here is the VERBOSE output from the make:

```
make VERBOSE=1

/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest -B/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build'
cd /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target ThreadTest
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/main.cpp.o
/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-g++    -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -std=c++11 -pthread   -o CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/main.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles 2
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/ThreadTest.cpp.o
/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-g++    -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -std=c++11 -pthread   -o CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/ThreadTest.cpp.o -c /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/ThreadTest.cpp
Linking CXX executable /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/OutputTest/DbricHost/ThreadTest
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-g++    -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -std=c++11 -pthread   -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/ThreadTest.cpp.o  -o /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/OutputTest/DbricHost/ThreadTest -rdynamic -lpthread 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles  1 2
[100%] Built target ThreadTest
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/mitydsp/Code/CommonSDK/source/Tests/ThreadTest/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

I've exhaustively looked in StackOverflow, Google, etc. -- and the suggestions I've come across are incorporated in the CMakeLists.txt, above.  But I still can't get the cmake executable to run properly on the target.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might want include the output from when you run `make VERBOSE=1`.  Maybe you are linking against a different thread library.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's linking against a different thread library, too.  Especially because of the `pthread_create - not found` instances during the cmake.  I can't find any cmake variables from the `FIND_PACKAGE(Threads)` call that indicate _where_ it found the pthreads library.  My build system has the native x86_64 compilers and two arm cross-compilers -- each with their own sysroot.

Comment: @f1fan44, that means `pthread_create` was not found when libpthread was not used. The third test shows it was found with the right library, and so cmake will use that library. Or should do. What does `ldd ThreadTest` show? Is it linking to libpthread.so ?

Comment: When the program succeeds ldd shows: `libpthread.so.0 => lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x428d0000)`  When it fails, ldd shows no libpthread at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by adding the `-Wl,--no-as-needed` linker option.  In the CMakeLists.txt file, it's done like this:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-as-needed ${THREADTEST_COMPILE_FLAG}")
```

Apparently the default for the gcc linker is `--as-needed` -- where the linker chooses not to link a library it thinks is not needed.  The interesting thing is that the straight g++ command line build correctly decides that libpthread is needed.  In the cmake case, g++ apparently decides that libpthread is not needed.  You'll see in the `make` output, above, that cmake gloms together a lot of g++ command line options with duplicates and other messiness.  I suspect that is probably the root issue.

Nevertheless, here is the CMakeLists.txt file that works.  Notice that for my case at least, the call to `FIND_PACKAGE(Threads REQUIRED)` was not required at all.

```
# cmake file for building the ThreadTest executable.  This requires c++11.
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.12)

# !!! Set up the compiler to use, first (i.e. before the PROJECT() call.)
# gcc location.
SET(CROSS_COMPILE_FULL
   "/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/i686-clsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi/arm-criticallink-linux-gnueabi-")
# sysroot location
SET(CROSS_COMPILE_FULL_HOST
   "/opt/criticallink/mityomapl138_20151114/sysroots/arm926ejste-criticallink-linux-gnueabi")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CROSS_COMPILE_FULL}gcc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CROSS_COMPILE_FULL}g++")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${CROSS_COMPILE_FULL_HOST}")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# The project will use the compiler specified above (or the default compiler for Windows.)
PROJECT(CommonSDK)

SET(MY_TEST_HOME "$ENV{TEST_HOME}")
SET(THREADTEST_COMPILE_FLAG "-std=c++11 -pthread")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${THREADTEST_COMPILE_FLAG}")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-as-needed ${THREADTEST_COMPILE_FLAG}")

SET(CUR_PROJECT_NAME ThreadTest)
SET(PROJECT_HOME_DIR "${MY_TEST_HOME}/${CUR_PROJECT_NAME}")
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "$ENV{TEST_EXEC_HOME}")

FILE(GLOB CUR_PROJECT_FILES "${PROJECT_HOME_DIR}/*.cpp" "${PROJECT_HOME_DIR}/*.h")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${CUR_PROJECT_NAME} ${CUR_PROJECT_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CUR_PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```